# Cannot expand struct - elixir/phoenix

Tags: struct, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to display a form on the screen. But I keep getting this error when I try to start the server. `locations_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/locations_controller.ex:5: Locations.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Locations`. BTW I'm new to elixir so I'm probably doing something really obvious wrong.

Here is my code:

### locations.controller.ex

```
 def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Locations.changeset(%Locations{})

    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end

  def create(conn, %{"locations" => %{ "start" => start, "end" => finish }}) do
    changeset = %AwesomeLunch.Locations{start: start, end: finish}
    Repo.insert(changeset)

    redirect conn, to: locations_path(conn, :index)
  end
```

### VIEW

```html
<h1>Hey There</h1>

<%= form_for @changeset, locations_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>

  <label>
    Start: <%= text_input f, :start %>
  </label>

  <label>
    End: <%= text_input f, :end %>
  </label>

  <%= submit "Pick An Awesome Lunch" %>

<% end %>
```

### model

```html
    defmodule AwesomeLunch.Locations do
  use AwesomeLunch.Web, :model

  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "locations" do
    field :start
    field :end
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:start, :end])
    |> validate_required([:start, :end])
  end
end
```

Like I said I'm getting this error:

```html
    locations_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/locations_controller.ex:5: Locations.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Locations
```

Comment: Not directly relevant to resolving the problem / question, but as I understand it, a Phoenix best practice is to **name your domain objects in the singular** rather than plural (eg. `defmodule AwesomeLunch.Location`, `LocationController`, etc.). That way you don't have the confusing conventions of sometimes referring to singular and sometimes referring to plural, like in the Rails world.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Modules in Elixir need to be referred to by their full name or an `alias` of it. You can either change all `Locations` to `AwesomeLunch.Locations`, or if you want to use a shorter name, you can call `alias` in that module:

```
defmodule AwesomeLunch.LocationsController do
  alias AwesomeLunch.Locations

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am developing an umbrella project and I was getting the same error some times.

If you create a struct declared in `App1`, and want to use it in  `App2` you have to add `App1` to `App2` as dependency. If you don't do this and If `App2` loaded before `App1` the error occurs.

Example:
`{:app1, in_umbrella: true}`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for me it worked configuring the controller, this way:

```
defmodule AwesomeLunch.LocationsController do
  use AwesomeLunch.Web, :controller

  alias AwesomeLunch.Locations

  ...
end
```